# Implementing a graph convolutional layer, pixel2mesh example

Tags: machine-learning, python, graph-theory, spectral-analysis, graph-neural-network

I'm trying to read through some python code in order to understand how to implement a Graph Convolutional Layer.

I was particularly interested in [pixel2mesh](https://github.com/nywang16/Pixel2Mesh), digging through the code I've found the following class:

```
class GraphConvolution(Layer):
    """Graph convolution layer."""
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, placeholders, dropout=False,
                 sparse_inputs=False, act=tf.nn.relu, bias=True, gcn_block_id=1,
                 featureless=False, **kwargs):
        super(GraphConvolution, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        if dropout:
            self.dropout = placeholders['dropout']
        else:
            self.dropout = 0.

        self.act = act
        if gcn_block_id == 1:
            self.support = placeholders['support1']
        elif gcn_block_id == 2:
            self.support = placeholders['support2']
        elif gcn_block_id == 3:
            self.support = placeholders['support3']

        self.sparse_inputs = sparse_inputs
        self.featureless = featureless
        self.bias = bias

        # helper variable for sparse dropout
        self.num_features_nonzero = 3#placeholders['num_features_nonzero']

        with tf.variable_scope(self.name + '_vars'):
            for i in range(len(self.support)):
                self.vars['weights_' + str(i)] = glorot([input_dim, output_dim],
                                                        name='weights_' + str(i))
            if self.bias:
                self.vars['bias'] = zeros([output_dim], name='bias')

        if self.logging:
            self._log_vars()

    def _call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs

        # dropout
        if self.sparse_inputs:
            x = sparse_dropout(x, 1-self.dropout, self.num_features_nonzero)
        else:
            x = tf.nn.dropout(x, 1-self.dropout)

        # convolve
        supports = list()
        for i in range(len(self.support)):
            if not self.featureless:
                pre_sup = dot(x, self.vars['weights_' + str(i)],
                              sparse=self.sparse_inputs)
            else:
                pre_sup = self.vars['weights_' + str(i)]
            support = dot(self.support[i], pre_sup, sparse=True)
            supports.append(support)
        output = tf.add_n(supports)

        # bias
        if self.bias:
            output += self.vars['bias']

return self.act(output)
```

And I think the actual convolution implementation is given by

```
# convolve
        supports = list()
        for i in range(len(self.support)):
            if not self.featureless:
                pre_sup = dot(x, self.vars['weights_' + str(i)],
                              sparse=self.sparse_inputs)
            else:
                pre_sup = self.vars['weights_' + str(i)]
            support = dot(self.support[i], pre_sup, sparse=True)
            supports.append(support)
output = tf.add_n(supports)
```

It is my understanding that in order to compute a convolution over a graph I need to compute an eigenvector analysis over the Combinatorial Laplacian (or simply Laplacian matrix) defined by the underlying graph, the reason behind this its because they would need to apply some sort of Fourier analysis, where the Fourier transform has an appropriate definition on a graph, and it depends on the Laplacian as mentioned.

Can anyone explain to me how a Graph convolutional layer is usually implemented and how the bits of code I'm showing reflect that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that snippet of code originated from [here](https://github.com/tkipf/gcn).

Let $g \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be some filter defined on the spatial domain, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be the input signal. Let $L$ by the laplacian, which is diagonalized as $L = U\Lambda U^T$. Recall that eigenvectors of the laplacian form a basis for functions on the graph.

Then by "inspiration from convolution theorem" we have

$$g * x = U(U^Tg \odot U^Tx) = UGU^Tx$$ where $G$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of the elements in $U^Tg$.

Inspired by the fact that $L^k_{i,j}$ is non-zero only if the distance between $i$ and $j$ is less than $k$ (we want some locality property), and $L^k = U\Lambda^kU^T$, a common choice of $G$ is $\sum_{k \leq K} \theta_k \Lambda^k$, and $K = 1$ is a common approximation, leaving us with $$g * x \approx \theta L x$$

For vector-valued signal $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\, \times\, c}$, and weight matrix $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{c\, \times\, c'}$ this becomes $Y = LX\Theta$.

In the code above, `support` $= L$, and `self.vars['weights']` $ = \Theta$. You can trace how `support` is computed in the code -- I believe this implementation actually uses a fast chebyshev polynomial approximation to the sum of powers $\Lambda$ mentioned above.

Comment: I think for graphs the convolution is defined in terms of eigen function of the laplacian, there's no convolution theorem as far as I know on graphs.

Comment: thanks, i've edited the answer accordingly to correct

Comment: Didn't mean to be pedantic, I'm not an expert and maybe there was some other definition I'm not aware of.

Comment: Okay, I know the explanation is using graph laplacian and cheby poly. However, in the original implementation, it's nothing, but augmented normalized adjacency matrix. https://github.com/tkipf/gcn/blob/bdcc4dd9314d7794d68b4c826c46b4b53137c05c/gcn/utils.py#L132